# How do I create a spacing between two elevated buttons in bottomBar Navigation?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[image]

I am confused on how can I make the padding look more user Friendly. Also I want to keep a symmetric distance between all 3 items on the bottom Navigation Bar. How can I do So?

Comment: please include your code where you have used these two elevated buttons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add  `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,` inside the Row() widget, this will make sure that the children have same space around them.

Answer (score 0):

use `SizedBox` between 2 `Widgets`

```
const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
```

or one `Widget` wrap with `Padding` and give one side **padding like left or Right**

```
const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0)),
```

or use `Spacer` between 2 `Widgets`

```
const Spacer(),
```

or you can use in `Row Widgets`

```
Row(
// you can use anyone of them, this properties space given equally according properties
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      Text("Text 1"),
      Text("Text 2"),
      Text("Text 3"),
    ]
)
```

Comment: SizedBox gives me an error

Comment: whats the error please add code